# My database wont update but no error found

Tags: php, javascript, sql, html

please help, i have been working on this for 2 days now, i cant seem to know why my database won't update. the function of my program is this

from the main page,when a file's status is **'Pending'** a pop up link appears that directs it to the confirm.php
my confirm.php ask the admin if he/she would approve the file uploaded by the sa. the confirm.php contains to link buttons, **YES** and **NO**. when the admin clicks on yes,The database should change my confirmation table from **PENDING** to **APPROVED**. that also goes with the no, but it changes **PENDING** to **NOTAPPROVED**. I'm guessing the problem is within the confirm.php or the membersite.php where all functions are located. here is my code(I wont right it all because its too long)

**NOTE problem solved thanks guys

Comment: The first thing you need to do is relax.

Comment: The second thing you need to do is fix the SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query($yes)` is your problem. You already did your query the line above there and you're trying to do another query with something that is not an SQL string and so the page dies. Pending your autocommit setting, it's possible nothing gets changed.

The second problem I see is that the page likely doesn't make it, because you close the window on click. Check your webserver logs if you ever see a request for "confirm.php?yes=123". You should probably test confirm.php with a valid employee number in your browser. If that is working, your problem is not the php code or query, but the fact that the javascript prevents the request from ever getting sent to the server.

Comment: Mel, thanks for the reply, i tried removing the mysql_query($yes) and the mysql_query($no) but my database still wont update

Comment: i dont think the javascipt is the reason, since my confirm.php is a popup menu. I have used one method like the one i use right now which allows user to input files into the database. that part works perfectly. Is there anyway i could fix  this? thanks for the halp

Comment: i already solved it! the onclick button realy is the cause!, but by removing it, the pop up window ("confirm.php") wont close. however, i tired to revise it until it works! thanks for all who replied :) esp Mel who gave me the idea

Answer (score 0):

first, try to set the error reporting to a debug level and then, u will probably see more, that helps you further:

php.ini
my.cnf
and your apache.conf

be sure to have a LogLevel debug in apache
and look for mysql / php errors in your logfile / webserver output.

May you try this and post the result here, if more help needed.

Comment: m not using an apache, im using the phpadmin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are forgetting to COMMIT your update?

If you are using InnoDB tables, and you have auto-commit turned off, then this might be the problem.

I think default MySQL behaviour is MyISAM tables (non-transactional), and auto-commit turned on, but who knows, maybe this is the problem you are having.

I could be showing my age here... I learned MySQL in 2000!  Things might be different these days.